# ChartJS Bar Chart is too short

Tags: javascript, chart.js, bar-chart

I want the chart to be much larger regardless of the values. Currently, the chart is the height in the picture and it does not change. This is the complete configuration for the chart I currently have. Is it possible for the chart to have more height regardless of the dataset values?

[image]

```
const KYCctx = document.getElementById('kycChart').getContext('2d');

const KYCChart = new Chart(KYCctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Approved", "Denied", "Pending"],
        datasets: [{
            data: [65, 59, 80],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(203, 55, 55, 0.2)',
                ' rgba(39, 187, 101, 0.5)',
                'rgba(255, 171, 45, 0.1)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                ' rgba(203, 55, 55, 1)',
                'rgba(34, 195, 107, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 171, 45, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                grid: {
                    color: 'rgb(33,34,37)'
                }
            }
        },
        plugins: {

            legend: {
                position: 'bottom',
                labels: {
                    usePointStyle: true,
                    pointStyle: 'circle',
                    boxWidth: 6,
                    generateLabels: (chart) => {
                        console.log(chart);
                        return chart.data.labels.map(
                            (label, index) => ({
                                text: label,
                                fillStyle: chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[index],
                                strokeStyle: chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[index],
                            }
                            )
                        )
                    }

                }
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                align: "start",
                color: "#ffff",
                font: {
                    size: 18,
                    weight: 700,
                    lineHeight: 2
                },
                padding: {
                    bottom: 20
                }
            }
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could explicitly define the `height` on the `canvas`.

```
<canvas id="kycChart" height="400"></canvas>
```

```js
const KYCChart = new Chart('kycChart', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Approved", "Denied", "Pending"],
    datasets: [{
      data: [65, 59, 80],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(203, 55, 55, 0.2)',
        ' rgba(39, 187, 101, 0.5)',
        'rgba(255, 171, 45, 0.1)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        ' rgba(203, 55, 55, 1)',
        'rgba(34, 195, 107, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 171, 45, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        grid: {
          color: 'rgb(33,34,37)'
        }
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom',
        labels: {
          usePointStyle: true,
          pointStyle: 'circle',
          boxWidth: 6,
          generateLabels: (chart) => {
            return chart.data.labels.map(
              (label, index) => ({
                text: label,
                fillStyle: chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[index],
                strokeStyle: chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[index],
              })
            )
          }
        }
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        align: "start",
        color: "#ffff",
        font: {
          size: 18,
          weight: 700,
          lineHeight: 2
        },
        padding: {
          bottom: 20
        }
      }
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="kycChart" height="400"></canvas>
```